# How to concatenate an echoed string to include literal single quotes around a value pulled from MySQL?

Tags: php, quoting, mysql, string, echo

I've run into a slight dilemma when I try to contain a value from an array of data pulled from MySQL inside single quotes. This would normally be a no brainer, but I run into issues since it's inside php tags and I'm forced to echo the line.. I just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

**The part I'm having issues with is:**

```
onclick='return toggleMe(" .$row['Name']. ")'>
```

**Here's a snippet of my code.**

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))


{
      echo "                    <tr>\n";
      echo "                        <td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>\n";
      echo "                        <td><a style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='return toggleMe(" .$row['Name']. ")'><img id='" . $row['Name'] . "_image' src='/images/go_button.png' style='border:0;align:left;margin-right:5px;' /></a><div id='" . $row['Name'] . "' style='display:none;'>" . $row['Name'] . "</div></td>\n";
      echo "                        <td>$ " . $row['Price'] . "</td>\n";
}
```

Here's my current output when it's generated to a page (pulled from view source):

```
onclick="return toggleMe(Value)"
```

Here's my desired output when generated to a page (pulled from view source):

```
onclick="return toggleMe('Value')"
```

Comment: This is not related to Unix at all, is it?

Comment: @HaukeLaging It isn't even related to PHP... it's a javascript question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's wrong. He wants to generate Javascript code with PHP. That the output happens to be Javascript does not affect the problem (thus neither the solution).

Comment: @Hauke Laging Well, not directly.. but, I do all of my coding on my Linux box (where the pages are hosted). Didn't really consider that.. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, something like (`\'`) should work, that is -

```
onclick='return toggleMe(\'" .$row['Name']. "\')'>
```

**EDIT**

Or, you could escape the double quotes -

```
onclick=\"return toggleMe('" .$row['Name']. "')\">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've tried multiple versions of what you just posted (including that).. Things get tricky since it's already being echoed within double quotes (which is a necessity when using JS inside php tags (referring to your comment above)).

Comment: @user62129 Edited. But I can't tell what you have tried if you don't include it in the question.